# Making a bracket like symbol no consider a match in specific syntax region in vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Suppose this text:

`{This text "contains two '}'" }`

In many filetypes if I press `%` on first `{` it'll jump to end of line ignoring first `}`.
How can I make match mechanism of vim to ignore `>` in a specific syntax region?

My exact problem happens in jsx files, consider this:

```
<SomeComponent
    //  >>> >  >>
    x='>>>> > >> >'
    onClick={() => {}}
/>
```

```
If i press `%` in the first character of first line it'll jump to the `>` in the fourth line instead of jumping to second character of last line. Some plugins handle the syntax for jsx for me and they define a special region for {() => {}} I want to disable match finding in this region just like how it's disabled in comments and strings.

### Disclaimer

I'm not trying to match `<` with `/>`. I just want `<` to match the right `>` not the one in js block (`=>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading https://github.com/isaacs/.vim/blob/master/macros/matchit.txt#L64 to make vim ignore a specific area of text while searching for matches you should activate matchit. By default it ignores comments and strings. If you want to add more syntax regions to ignored list you should set `b:match_skip` variable documented here: https://github.com/isaacs/.vim/blob/master/macros/matchit.txt#L218.
In my case, using `vim-javascript` and `vim-jsx` I had to set it to: `s:comment\|string\|jsArrowFunction` (its default value is 's:comment\|string'. I created this pull request for `vim-jsx` to handle it out of the box: https://github.com/sassanh/vim-jsx/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

So I can't answer your question exactly but I can give you some information about how the '%' motion works.

It looks through a list of 'matchpairs' (`:help matchpairs` for more info) that is essentially just a list containing pairs of characters that have been defined by whatever active syntax files are available for your current file along with plugins(like matchit.vim).

Looking through the help-docs, these pairs are restricted to only allow a single character -> character mapping so you can't actually extend it to allow `<` to match `/>` unfortunately. (`:set mps+=<:/>` blows up :( )

A possible solution(albeit not fantastic), might be to install the matchit.vim plugin and then always close your tags with the name of the tag in full. I.e. `<foobar> some stuff </foobar>`. The matchit.vim adds what's inside the tags `<>` and adds it to the `%` pair-list. I'm not entirely sure what magic he's using to have a string pair, but perhaps looking at his source might reveal a solution to getting `<` to match `/>`.

Best of luck!

Comment: I don't want `<` to match `/>`, I just want it to match the right `>` not the one in the js block (`=>`).

Comment: I do have matchit.vim.

Comment: Ah, the reason I mentioned `/>` was that you can guarantee that the closing `<` will always be accompanied by the prepended `/` when closing an html block.

Another thing I forgot to mention was that when I was testing this yesterday my syntax highlighter was freaking out about the JS block and was saying that my `>` closing tag was invalid(it was highlighting in red).

Perhaps this could mean that I didn't have html JS syntax correctly installed on my machine(Since I rarely do html/js this might be correct). That might be something worth looking into on your side though.